How to Resolve C++ File Debugging Issues in VS Code?
cl.exe build and debug is only usable when VS Code is run from the Developer Command Prompt for VS.
This message pops up while i am trying to debug the issue, as per internet I saw this error was based on the path of the MSVC file in the vscode in the c/c++ edit configuration UI panel and changed the compiler path to the MSVC file, which I think i fixed it but its still showing error while debuggin a cpp file .
Changed the the compiler path in the c/c++ configurations from MINGW/g++/exe file to a MSVC file but still facing the same issue after changing it .

One option is to first start the Developer Command Prompt for VS, and then run VS Code from there. Have you tried that? The compiler and debugger from Visual Studio uses its own config, and don't care much about a hacked VSCode config.

VSCode is complicated, it doesn't make sense to fight it. Just start VSCode from the developer command prompt. If that really is too much then pick a different IDE, VS Code is not compulsory.

The easiest way to deal with this is to open VS Code from the Developer Command Prompt for VS.

Copy the path to the folder or file you want to open.
Search for "Developer Command Prompt for VS" in your start menu and open it.
In the command prompt, type (quotation marks included):

code "{path}"
For a folder, this might look something like:
code "C:\users\nilotpal\repos\project
Or for a file:
code "C:\users\nilotpal\repos\project\main.cpp
